# How do I resolve page cannot be displayed issue while configuring a Wordpress blog?

Tags: mysql, setup, wordpress

I have installed a WordPress blog on different webhosting accounts but now I'm trying to install WP on my own server and running into issues.

Here's the issue. I've setup my own database using phpMyAdmin and everything seems correct. I've setup the changes to the config file. It looks as though it is setup correctly but it doesn't seem to be connecting to the CSS...

[image]

Ignoring the CSS issue I forge forward and try to setup the blog but after creating my admin account etc, and trying to access the blog or dashboard I get the "Page can't be displayed" page.

Is this an issue with my server, WordPress, or am I just missing something?

Comment: can you post a screenshot with the URL in view?

Comment: @Jason: which version of Apache server are you using? XAMPP on Windows? or Linux ?

Comment: I'm not a server guy, I don't know what baseURL is, or how to find it. I'm using Google to no avail right now.

Comment: I'm using Windows

Answer (score 1):

Your baseURL is not setup correctly for the app. I forget exactly how to set it up if you cant get into the admin pages, there is a config file somwhere. Google is your friend.

Comment: That or you could just help me with a link or something.

Comment: can you please post a screenshot with the url in it?

Answer (score 0):

If your base URL is the problem, then the link below should help. it shows you how to modify the baseURL manually.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

you simply need to modify the wp-config.php file.